# Reactjs Changing the component

Tags: reactjs

I have a Login function which is working. I am doing Login verification with mongodb.

```
  render() {
    const { isAuthed } = this.state
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header as="h1">Login</Header>
        <p>
          A MongoDB Stitch  authentication using
          Email/Password.
            </p>
        {isAuthed ? (
          <UserInfo user={this.client.auth.user} logoutUser={this.logout} />
        ) : (
            <Login loginUser={this.login} />
          )}
      </Container>
    )
  }
```

Userinfo:

```
 <div>
      <Header as="h2">User Info</Header>
      <p>You are logged in using {user.loggedInProviderName}.</p>
      <List>
        {picture && (
          <List.Item key="picture">
            <Image src={picture} size="small" />
          </List.Item>
        )}
        {dataKeys.map(key => {
          return (
            data[key] && (
              <List.Item key={key}>
                <List.Header>{key}</List.Header>
                <List.Description>{data[key]}</List.Description>
              </List.Item>
            )
          )
        })}
      </List>
      <Button
        primary
        onClick={() => {
          logoutUser()
        }}
      >
        Logout
      </Button>
```

This is working.
I have one more component which should be called when the Authentication is successful.
The other component is working standalone. It's called Display.js.

I am having issues integrating

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question? what is the issue on integrating exactly and please share the display.js also

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get this working by modifying the following code

UserInfo user={this.client.auth.user}.

Instead of UserInfo I have the component name I want to forward it to